# Gremlin: Add edges to multiple vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have vertices `[song1, song2, song3, user]`.

I want to add edges `listened` from `user` to the songs.

I have the following:

`g.V().is(within(song1, song2, song3)).addE('listened').from(user)`

However I'm getting the following error:

> No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.from() is applicable for argument types: (org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex) values: [v[4344]]
>   Possible solutions: sort(), drop(int), sum(), find(), grep(), sort(groovy.lang.Closure)

Of course, I can iterate through them one at a time instead but a single query would be nice:

```
user.addEdge('listened', song1)
user.addEdge('listened', song2)
user.addEdge('listened', song3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `from()` modulator accepts two things:

1. a step label or
2. a traversal

A single vertex or a list of vertices can easily be turned into a traversal by wrapping it in `V()`. Also, note that `g.V().is(within(...))` will most likely end up being a full scan over all vertices; it pretty much depends on the provider implementation, but you should prefer to use `g.V(<list of vertices>)` instead. Thus your traversal should look more like any of these:

```
g.V().is(within(song1, song2, song3)).
  addE('listened').from(V(user)) // actually bad, as it's potentially a full scan

g.V(song1, song2, song3).
  addE('listened').from(V(user))

g.V(user).as('u').
  V(within(song1, song2, song3)).
  addE('listened').from('u')
```

Comment: Is `V()` the same as `g.V()`? If not where can I get it from the tinkerpop library, assuming I'm using java?

Comment: `V()` is a global vertex lookup; it can be the start of traversal (`g.V()`) or, like in the examples above, a mid-traversal global vertex lookup (`__.V()`).

Comment: Do I need a command like `iterate()` in order to trigger this? I see the changes in through gremlin but not through java.

Comment: Yes, `.iterate()` if you only want to get the edges added or `.toList()` if you also want the new edges to be returned by the traversal.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it answers my original question. However, I still can't get the edges added and returned with `.toList()` in Java.

Comment: You get an error message or something? Perhaps share your code in a Gist, would be easier to spot any bugs in it.

Comment: It's pretty much with what you gave me (scala btw) `val edges = g.V(songVertices).addE("listened"l).from(__.V(userVertex)).toList`. `edges` is empty and `songVertices` is a `Set()`

Comment: I figured it out. gremlin requires java objects and so I had to convert the `Set` to a java type first.